# Caesar cipher in cs50 :Why does my function only encrypt the first letter and then copies that information to all the other letters?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, cs50, caesar-cipher

I'm doing the cs50 intro to Computer Science and I'm on the problem set where we need to create a Caesar cipher. My problem is that my program only encrypts the first letter and then copies that to all the letters in plaintext. I've tried everything. Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool only_digits(string argv[]);
int rotate(string plaintext, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if(!(argc == 2 && only_digits(argv))) // dont't mind this
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int key = atoi(argv[1]); //don't mind these
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");

    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++) //I think the problem is here in my else statement.
    {
        if(!isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
        }
        else
        {
        printf("%c", rotate(plaintext, key));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

}

bool only_digits(string argv[]) // dont'mind this
{
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
     if(!isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int rotate(string plaintext, int key) // it uses this function to encrypt
{
    int cipher = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        if (plaintext[i] == 'Z' || plaintext[i] == 'z')
        {
           cipher = 0 + plaintext[i] - 26 + key;
           return cipher;
        }
        else if (isalpha(plaintext[i]))
        {
           cipher = 0 + plaintext[i] + key;
           return cipher;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Here's a picture of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttvfZ.png)

Comment: `printf("%c", rotate(plaintext, key));` ... how does `rotate()` know what specific charcater inside `plaintext` to rotate?

Comment: @pmg I don't know I thought the for loops would tell rotate() that

Comment: `rotate()` simply receives its arguments: the whole string (`plaintext`) and the whole key. It should also receive the current index. Something like `printf("%c", rotate(plaintext, key, i));` with the appropriate changes in the function. of course.

Comment: You have a loop `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)` Insaide that loop you call  `rotate`. Inside `rotate` you have another loop `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)`. Explain why you need both.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. If I don't use both then only one letter gets printed out as 'ciphertext:  ' no matter how many letters you input in 'plaintext: '

Comment: @pmg changing " printf("%c", rotate(plaintext, key)); " to " printf("%c", rotate(&plaintext[i], key)); " fixed it completely. Thanks again :)

Comment: Good one @DrinKurtishi... maybe you could just send the single character instead of the address: `printf("%c", rotate(plaintext[i], key));`. After all that is really the only thing you're interested in inside `rotate()` function. BTW: your loop inside `rotate()` terminates with the `return` right on the first time through. You can just as well just start `i` with `0` and omit the `for` altogether.

Comment: Don't explain what happens if you don't do X, explain what X **does**.